# Extract common path from URI and Web Root

Tags: php, perl, url-routing

I have a self-built MVC fw with a router routing URLs such that the common `example.com/controller/action` is used. I'm running into issues when my application is deployed within a sub-directory such as

`example.com/my_app/controller/action/?var=value`

My router thinks `my_app` is the name of the controller now and `controller` is the method.

My current solution is to manually ask for any sub directory name in a config at install. I'd like to do this manually. See my question below and let me know if I'm going about solving this the wrong way and asking the wrong question.

My question: 
if I have two paths, how do I truncate the common pieces from the end of one and remove it from the end of the other.

A = /var/www/my_app/pub
B = /my_app/pub/cntrl/actn

What's your quickest one liner to remove /my_app/pub from B and remain with /cntrl/actn? 
Basically looking for a perl-esque way of getting the common denominator like string.

Thanks for any input

Comment: Are you looking for PHP or Perl?

Comment: Either is fine, but my code is PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would solve this is adding this logic to the [front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) (the file to which your server sends all nonexistant file requests, usually index.php).

```
$fontControllerPath = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$frontControllerPathLength = strlen($fontControllerPath);

$frontControllerFileName = basename($fontControllerPath);
$frontControllerFileNameLength = strlen($frontControllerFileName);

$subdirectoryLength = $frontControllerPathLength - $frontControllerFileNameLength;

$url = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $subdirectoryLength - 1);
```

[Here's a codepad demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dADZFT).

What does this do? If the front controller is located (relative to the www root) in: `/subdir/myapp/`, then it's [`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) would be `/subdir/myapp/index.php`. The actual request URI is contained in [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). Let's say, for example, that it is `/subdir/myapp/controller/action?extras=stuff`. To remove the subdirectory prefix we need to find the length of it. That is found by subtracting the length of the script name (retrieved from [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename)) from the length of the script's name relative to the www root.

```
File that receives request: /subdir/myapp/index.php (length = 23)
Filename: index.php                                 (length = 9)
                                                                 -
-------------------------------------------------------------------
                                               14 chars to remove

/subdir/mpapp/controller/action?extras=stuff
              ^
              Cut off everything before here
```

Comment: Not exactly what I need but very close! Here's the final solution on one line `substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],0,strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])-strlen(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])))` I just changed substr() to get the first part of the path (/subdir/mpapp/) instead of the controller/action part.

Answer (score 3):

```
my @physical_parts = split qr{/}, $physical_path;
my @logical_parts  = split qr{/}, $logical_path;

my @physical_suffix;
my @logical_prefix;
my $found = 0;
while (@physical_parts && @logical_parts) {
    unshift @physical_suffix, pop(@physical_parts);
    push @logical_prefix, shift(@logical_parts);

    if (@physical_suffix ~~ @logical_prefix) {
       $found = 1;
       last;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may work, it's too brute force. This is going to be done every single page load, so need something quick. PhpMyCoder is more in the lines of what I need (I'll reduce his solution)

Comment: You said to start from `example.com/my_app/controller/action/?var=value`. I followed your instructions, whereas PhpMyCoder started from `$SCRIPT_NAME` (`/controller/action/?var=value`). If that's acceptable, sure, go for it.